# QTreeWidget right click menu

Tags: qt, popupmenu, qtreewidget

I looked around and it seems that the problem is present not only for tree widget but also for other widgets. But in my case, I found a solution, although an incomplete one. I am adding actions to my tree widget, so that when you right click on it, a popup with these actions appears. However, when I add items to my tree widget and I right click on them, the same popup appears.
What I would like to do is that when you right click on the tree widget, a tree widget popup menu appears and when you right click on items, another corresponding popup menu appears. Does anybody knows how to do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First you should set the [context menu policy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#contextMenuPolicy-prop) to [`CustomContextMenu`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ContextMenuPolicy-enum):

```
treeView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
```

Then you can connect to the [`QWidget::customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint&)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#customContextMenuRequested) signal and show your context menu.

Comment: It seems to be more complicated that I tought. So practically I need to do connect the customContextMenuRequested signal to my slot?

Comment: Yes, you should have a slot that will show your custom context menu after catching that signal.

Answer (score 29):

First,config QTreeWidget to response(emit signal) right mouse click:

```
treeWidget->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
```

Second,connect the signal with your slot "MainWindow::prepareMenu":

```
connect(treeWidget,&QTreeWidget::customContextMenuRequested,this,&MainWindow::prepareMenu);
```

Third,create context menu in the slot:

```
void MainWindow::prepareMenu( const QPoint & pos )
{
QTreeWidget *tree = treeWid;

QTreeWidgetItem *nd = tree->itemAt( pos );

qDebug()<<pos<<nd->text(0);


QAction *newAct = new QAction(QIcon(":/Resource/warning32.ico"), tr("&New"), this);
newAct->setStatusTip(tr("new sth"));
connect(newAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(newDev()));


QMenu menu(this);
menu.addAction(newAct);

QPoint pt(pos);
menu.exec( tree->mapToGlobal(pos) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `QTreeWidgetItem *nd = tree->itemAt( pos );`!

Answer (score 10):

For those who prefer to use designer more, here is  another way to do it:

#### 1) Set context menu policy to custom context menu

Either by code:

```
ui->treeWidget->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
```

or using graphical designer, click on the tree widget and set it using Property Editor:

[image]

#### 2) Create Handler function

In designer, right click on the treeWidget and select "Go to Slot..." option. A window similar to this will appear:

[image]

Click on the "CustomContextMenuRequested(QPoint)" option. Handler function will be defined, declared, and it will be connected automatically.

```
void MainWindow::on_treeWidget_customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &pos)
{
  // this function will be called on right click
}
```

This step can also be done by defining and connecting the slot function yourself.

#### 3) Create the options on the context menu.

[image]

Go to action editor tab (Usually docked at the bottom of designer). Add actions you want to have on context menu by clicking new button on top left. You will encounter such an interface :

[image]

You can (optionally) have a tooltip or icon for the action, or make it checkable. You can crate a shortcut like Ctrl+C for a copy action.

#### 4) Create the menu and fire it

```
void MainWindow::on_treeWidget_customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &pos)
{
    QMenu menu(this); // add menu items
    menu.addAction(ui->actionDelete);
    menu.addEdit(ui->actionDelete);
    ...

    ui->actionDelete->setData(QVariant(pos)); // if you will need the position data save it to the action

    menu.exec( ui->treeWidget->mapToGlobal(pos) );
}
```

#### 5) Create handler functions for each action

Like in step 2, either create slot function and connect it manually, or right-click on on an action, click the "Go to slots..." option and select triggered() slot.

[image]

#### 6) Lastly, apply your logic in the slot function

```
void MainWindow::on_actionEdit_triggered()
{
    QTreeWidgetItem *clickedItem = ui->treeWidget->itemAt(ui->actionDelete->data().toPoint());

    // your logic
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at overloading QAbstractItemModel and providing your own OnContextMenuRequested. Via this function you can have different items create different context menus.

Here's some shortened pseudo-ish code from one of my projects that may be helpful:

```
void MyModel::OnContextMenuRequested(const QModelIndex& index, const QPoint& globalPos)
{
// find 'node' corresponding to 'index'

vector<pair<string,BaseNode*> > actions = node->GetActions(true);
if(actions.size()==0) return;

// the ptr list helps us delete the actions
boost::ptr_list<QObject> actionPtrList;
QList<QAction*> qtActions;
for(unsigned int i=0;i<actions.size();i++)
{
    QAction* act = new QAction(actions[i].first.c_str(),NULL);
    act->setData(qVariantFromValue(actions[i].second));
    actionPtrList.push_back(act);
    qtActions.append(act);
}

// create and show the context menu
QMenu *menu = new QMenu("Item actions",NULL);
actionPtrList.push_back(menu);
QAction* act = menu->exec(qtActions,globalPos);
if(act==NULL) return;

// act on the resulting action 'act'
}
```

Comment: There's no reason for this to be in the model though. It's a signal from the view, which the model should typically not know about.